# dealing with 'worked time'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, date, time

I'm working on an app that will track the worked time from users, and then, generate graphics from this data...
Having in mind that they can start any task today and done it tomorrow, I can't save an `Date`...
By now, I'm saving an integer field like `hours` and a integer `minute`...
Is there a way (some gem, maybe) to help me dealing with this kind of problem?
Or any other approach?
Thanks

My class `Atendimento` that contains all necessary data

```
class Atendimento < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :horas, :minutos, :empresa, :tipo_atendimento, :observacao, :empresa_id, :tipoatendimento_id

  belongs_to :empresa
  belongs_to :tipo_atendimento, :foreign_key => 'tipoatendimento_id'
  belongs_to :usuario

  validates :horas, :minutos, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved the worked time as seconds :)

Answer (score 1):

I would add two datetime columns to your database to track the start and stop timestamps of the event. Then you can just subtract the two values to get the time elapsed.

Comment: I wasnt very clear...I can't do this, because the user can start the task when there are only 5 minutes left to the end of the business hours and continue the task another day...he can even start the task today, and done the task in a week

Answer (score 1):

Instead of three fields you should add the starting and ending times as timestamps. You can do it by adding these lines to the migration file:

```
add_column :tasks, :started_at, :timestamp
add_column :tasks, :ended_at, :timestamp
```

In the model you can then use these timestamps for calculations.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :started_at, :ended_at
  validates :started_at, presence: true
  validates :ended_at, presence: true

  # Returns the duration of the task in seconds
  def duration
    ended_at - started_at
  end
end
```

Comment: please, see my comment on @Beerlington's answer

Comment: @LuizE. Okay. I would still record the start and end timestamps into the database like this. Then you just need have to come up with more complex logic to the duration function. You may also want to take the weekends and holidays into account if the task can go over the weekend. Perhaps somebody can scetch some pseudo code? (I may even be able to do it a bit later).

Comment: @LuizE. I suggest you have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708881/counting-regular-working-days-in-a-given-period-of-time

Comment: @LuizE. So you should be able to calculate the number of full working days in task's time range and multiply it with the amount working seconds per each working day. In addition to that you have to, of course, add the remaining hours from the first and last day of the time range. Bad explanation, but I hope you get the point :).